# Wide table spanning multiple pages using longtable and landscape packages

Tags: tables, longtable, landscape

I am using the `longtable` and `landscape` package in the hope it would allow my very wide table to be read easily across multiple pages without breaks. However, it only spans one page and any extra content is just cut off (which I didn't think would be the case with longtable). How do I fix it?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt,notitlepage]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel} %francais, polish, spanish, ...
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\voffset}{0cm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{0cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{0cm}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
 \begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{cc|ccccccccccccccccccc|cccccccccccccccccccccc}
Tail Config & alpha & Temperature [K] & Barometric Pressure [kPa] & Velocity [m/s] & Density [kgm-3] & Viscosity [] & Dynamic Pressure [Pa] & Re [-] & Lift [lbf] & Left Bar & Right Bar & Average & Drag [lbf] & Left Bar & Right Bar & Average & Moment [lbf ft] & Left Bar & Right Bar & Average & Lift [lbf] & Lift [N] & Drag [lbf] & Drag [N] & Moment [lbf-ft] & M\_{io} [lbf ft] & Moment [lbf-ft] & Moment [Nm] & cltu [-] & cdtu [-] & cmtu [-] & Cl [-] & Cd [-] & Cmp [-] & cdi [-] & cdsupports [-] & CD [-] & True alpha & cl2 [-] & delta cm & cmp [-] & cmg [-] \\
\hline
\hline
No tail & -2    & 290.0 & 101.65 & 37.09 & 1.22  & 1.82E-05 & 8.40E+02 & 3.93E+05 & -2.10 & -5    & 5     & 0.0   & 1.235 & -1    & 0     & -0.5  & 0.474 & -1    & 0     & -0.5  & 2.10  & 9.34  & 1.235 & 5.491 & -0.454 & -0.1074 & -0.347 & -0.470 & 0.09  & 0.051 & -0.028 & 0.08  & 0.048 & -0.026 & 0.000 & 0.018 & 0.031 & -1.96 & 0.01  & -     & -0.026 & - \\
No tail & 0     & 300.0 & 101.65 & 37.03 & 1.18  & 1.87E-05 & 8.09E+02 & 3.69E+05 & -6.04 & -2    & 5     & 1.5   & 1.243 & -3    & 0     & -1.5  & 0.095 & -1    & 0     & -0.5  & 6.03  & 26.80 & 1.242 & 5.522 & -0.075 & 0.0000 & -0.075 & -0.102 & 0.26  & 0.053 & -0.006 & 0.24  & 0.050 & -0.006 & 0.001 & 0.017 & 0.034 & 0.13  & 0.06  & -     & -0.006 & - \\
No tail & 2     & 301.1 & 101.65 & 36.90 & 1.18  & 1.88E-05 & 8.01E+02 & 3.65E+05 & -9.83 & -3    & 3     & 0.0   & 1.322 & 0     & 0     & 0.0   & -0.331 & 0     & 0     & 0.0   & 9.83  & 43.73 & 1.322 & 5.881 & 0.331 & 0.1298 & 0.201 & 0.273 & 0.43  & 0.057 & 0.017 & 0.40  & 0.054 & 0.016 & 0.002 & 0.017 & 0.039 & 2.22  & 0.16  & -     & 0.016 & - \\
No tail & 4     & 301.5 & 101.64 & 36.81 & 1.17  & 1.88E-05 & 7.96E+02 & 3.64E+05 & -13.53 & -2    & 1     & -0.5  & 1.470 & -3    & 0     & -1.5  & -0.707 & -1    & 0     & -0.5  & 13.54 & 60.21 & 1.469 & 6.532 & 0.727 & 0.2820 & 0.445 & 0.603 & 0.59  & 0.064 & 0.037 & 0.55  & 0.060 & 0.035 & 0.003 & 0.016 & 0.047 & 4.31  & 0.31  & -     & 0.035 & - \\
No tail & 6     & 302.2 & 101.66 & 36.73 & 1.17  & 1.88E-05 & 7.90E+02 & 3.61E+05 & -16.55 & -3    & 0     & -1.5  & 1.711 & 0     & 2     & 1.0   & -1.186 & 0     & 0     & 0.0   & 16.57 & 73.68 & 1.712 & 7.615 & 1.186 & 0.4566 & 0.729 & 0.989 & 0.73  & 0.075 & 0.062 & 0.68  & 0.071 & 0.058 & 0.005 & 0.016 & 0.059 & 6.38  & 0.47  & -     & 0.058 & - \\
No tail & 8     & 302.4 & 101.66 & 36.65 & 1.17  & 1.88E-05 & 7.87E+02 & 3.60E+05 & -19.31 & -3    & 3     & 0.0   & 1.996 & 0     & 2     & 1.0   & -1.649 & 0     & 0     & 0.0   & 19.31 & 85.90 & 1.997 & 8.883 & 1.649 & 0.6536 & 0.995 & 1.350 & 0.85  & 0.088 & 0.085 & 0.80  & 0.083 & 0.080 & 0.006 & 0.016 & 0.074 & 8.44  & 0.64  & -     & 0.080 & - \\
No tail & 10    & 302.8 & 101.64 & 36.56 & 1.17  & 1.88E-05 & 7.81E+02 & 3.58E+05 & -21.66 & -1    & 2     & 0.5   & 2.340 & 0     & 0     & 0.0   & -2.097 & 0     & 0     & 0.0   & 21.66 & 96.33 & 2.340 & 10.409 & 2.097 & 0.8730 & 1.224 & 1.660 & 0.96  & 0.104 & 0.105 & 0.90  & 0.098 & 0.099 & 0.008 & 0.015 & 0.091 & 10.50 & 0.82  & -     & 0.099 & - \\
No tail & 12    & 303.0 & 101.64 & 36.47 & 1.17  & 1.89E-05 & 7.77E+02 & 3.57E+05 & -23.57 & -2    & 4     & 1.0   & 2.837 & 0     & 1     & 0.5   & -2.573 & 0     & 0     & 0.0   & 23.56 & 104.80 & 2.838 & 12.622 & 2.573 & 1.1148 & 1.458 & 1.977 & 1.05  & 0.127 & 0.126 & 0.99  & 0.119 & 0.118 & 0.010 & 0.015 & 0.114 & 12.54 & 0.98  & -     & 0.118 & - \\
\hline
1     & -2    & 302.6 & 101.63 & 37.10 & 1.17  & 1.88E-05 & 8.05E+02 & 3.64E+05 & -3.08 & -3    & 3     & 0.0   & 1.335 & 0     & 0     & 0.0   & 0.795 & -1    & 0     & -0.5  & 2.15  & 9.56  & 1.335 & 5.938 & 0.075 & -0.1074 & 0.182 & 0.247 & 0.09  & 0.058 & 0.015 & 0.09  & 0.054 & 0.014 & 0.000 & 0.018 & 0.037 & -1.95 & 0.01  & 0.001 & 0.016 & 0.014 \\
1     & 0     & 302.8 & 101.62 & 37.04 & 1.17  & 1.88E-05 & 8.02E+02 & 3.63E+05 & -7.59 & -4    & 3     & -0.5  & 1.350 & -1    & 1     & 0.0   & 1.035 & 0     & 1     & 0.5   & 6.67  & 29.65 & 1.350 & 6.005 & -0.205 & 0.0000 & -0.205 & -0.278 & 0.29  & 0.058 & -0.017 & 0.27  & 0.055 & -0.016 & 0.001 & 0.017 & 0.039 & 0.15  & 0.07  & 0.004 & -0.012 & -0.018 \\
1     & 2     & 303.2 & 101.64 & 36.95 & 1.17  & 1.89E-05 & 7.97E+02 & 3.61E+05 & -12.01 & -3    & 3     & 0.0   & 1.445 & -1    & 1     & 0.0   & 1.344 & 0     & 0     & 0.0   & 11.08 & 49.29 & 1.445 & 6.428 & -0.494 & 0.1298 & -0.624 & -0.846 & 0.48  & 0.063 & -0.052 & 0.45  & 0.059 & -0.049 & 0.002 & 0.017 & 0.044 & 2.25  & 0.21  & 0.007 & -0.042 & -0.053 \\
1     & 4     & 303.5 & 101.64 & 36.84 & 1.17  & 1.89E-05 & 7.92E+02 & 3.60E+05 & -16.08 & -1    & 2     & 0.5   & 1.635 & 0     & 4     & 2.0   & 1.616 & 0     & 0     & 0.0   & 15.15 & 67.37 & 1.637 & 7.282 & -0.766 & 0.2820 & -1.048 & -1.421 & 0.66  & 0.072 & -0.089 & 0.62  & 0.067 & -0.083 & 0.004 & 0.016 & 0.055 & 4.34  & 0.39  & 0.009 & -0.074 & -0.089 \\
1     & 6     & 303.6 & 101.63 & 36.78 & 1.17  & 1.89E-05 & 7.89E+02 & 3.59E+05 & -19.67 & -4    & 4     & 0.0   & 1.930 & -2    & 0     & -1.0  & 1.915 & -1    & 0     & -0.5  & 18.74 & 83.36 & 1.929 & 8.581 & -1.045 & 0.4566 & -1.502 & -2.036 & 0.82  & 0.085 & -0.127 & 0.77  & 0.080 & -0.120 & 0.006 & 0.016 & 0.070 & 6.43  & 0.60  & 0.012 & -0.108 & -0.126 \\
1     & 8     & 303.8 & 101.60 & 36.65 & 1.17  & 1.89E-05 & 7.82E+02 & 3.57E+05 & -22.93 & -3    & 1     & -1.0  & 2.305 & -2    & 2     & 0.0   & 2.161 & 0     & 0     & 0.0   & 22.01 & 97.91 & 2.305 & 10.253 & -1.311 & 0.6536 & -1.965 & -2.664 & 0.98  & 0.102 & -0.168 & 0.92  & 0.096 & -0.158 & 0.008 & 0.016 & 0.089 & 8.50  & 0.84  & 0.014 & -0.144 & -0.166 \\
1     & 10    & 304.0 & 101.61 & 36.58 & 1.16  & 1.89E-05 & 7.79E+02 & 3.56E+05 & -25.61 & 0     & 5     & 2.5   & 2.760 & -1    & 1     & 0.0   & 2.320 & 0     & 1     & 0.5   & 24.66 & 109.67 & 2.760 & 12.277 & -1.490 & 0.8730 & -2.363 & -3.204 & 1.10  & 0.123 & -0.203 & 1.03  & 0.116 & -0.191 & 0.011 & 0.015 & 0.111 & 10.57 & 1.07  & 0.015 & -0.175 & -0.200 \\
\hline
-3    & 0     & 304.3 & 101.60 & 36.97 & 1.16  & 1.89E-05 & 7.95E+02 & 3.59E+05 & -5.90 & -7    & 7     & 0.0   & 1.400 & 0     & 0     & 0.0   & -1.586 & 0     & 2     & 1.0   & 4.97  & 22.11 & 1.400 & 6.228 & 2.396 & 0.0000 & 2.396 & 3.249 & 0.22  & 0.061 & 0.202 & 0.20  & 0.057 & 0.190 & 0.000 & 0.017 & 0.041 & 0.11  & 0.04  & 0.003 & 0.193 & 0.188 \\
-3    & 2     & 304.4 & 101.61 & 36.98 & 1.16  & 1.89E-05 & 7.95E+02 & 3.59E+05 & -10.37 & -6    & 8     & 1.0   & 1.454 & -1    & 0     & -0.5  & -1.160 & 0     & 1     & 0.5   & 9.43  & 41.95 & 1.454 & 6.465 & 1.990 & 0.1298 & 1.860 & 2.522 & 0.41  & 0.063 & 0.157 & 0.39  & 0.060 & 0.147 & 0.001 & 0.017 & 0.044 & 2.21  & 0.15  & 0.006 & 0.153 & 0.144 \\
-3    & 4     & 304.8 & 101.63 & 36.89 & 1.16  & 1.89E-05 & 7.90E+02 & 3.57E+05 & -14.48 & 0     & 3     & 1.5   & 1.607 & -2    & 0     & -1.0  & -0.888 & 0     & 1     & 0.5   & 13.54 & 60.21 & 1.606 & 7.144 & 1.718 & 0.2820 & 1.436 & 1.947 & 0.59  & 0.071 & 0.122 & 0.56  & 0.066 & 0.114 & 0.003 & 0.016 & 0.053 & 4.31  & 0.31  & 0.008 & 0.123 & 0.110 \\
-3    & 6     & 305.1 & 101.61 & 36.85 & 1.16  & 1.90E-05 & 7.88E+02 & 3.56E+05 & -18.04 & -1    & 3     & 1.0   & 1.860 & 0     & 0     & 0.0   & -0.352 & -1    & 0     & -0.5  & 17.10 & 76.06 & 1.860 & 8.274 & 1.222 & 0.4566 & 0.765 & 1.038 & 0.75  & 0.082 & 0.065 & 0.71  & 0.077 & 0.061 & 0.005 & 0.016 & 0.066 & 6.39  & 0.50  & 0.011 & 0.072 & 0.055 \\
-3    & 8     & 305.2 & 101.62 & 36.77 & 1.16  & 1.90E-05 & 7.84E+02 & 3.55E+05 & -21.32 & -3    & 4     & 0.5   & 2.181 & 0     & 2     & 1.0   & -0.106 & -1    & 0     & -0.5  & 20.39 & 90.68 & 2.182 & 9.706 & 0.976 & 0.6536 & 0.322 & 0.437 & 0.90  & 0.097 & 0.028 & 0.85  & 0.091 & 0.026 & 0.007 & 0.016 & 0.082 & 8.47  & 0.72  & 0.013 & 0.039 & 0.019 \\
-3    & 10    & 305.3 & 101.63 & 36.67 & 1.16  & 1.90E-05 & 7.80E+02 & 3.54E+05 & -24.05 & -3    & 3     & 0.0   & 2.584 & 0     & 0     & 0.0   & 0.037 & 0     & 0     & 0.0   & 23.12 & 102.84 & 2.584 & 11.494 & 0.813 & 0.8730 & -0.060 & -0.081 & 1.03  & 0.115 & -0.005 & 0.97  & 0.108 & -0.005 & 0.009 & 0.015 & 0.102 & 10.53 & 0.94  & 0.014 & 0.010 & -0.013 \\
-3    & 12    & 305.4 & 101.61 & 36.58 & 1.16  & 1.90E-05 & 7.75E+02 & 3.53E+05 & -26.49 & -5    & 0     & -2.5  & 3.191 & 0     & 0     & 0.0   & 0.372 & 0     & 0     & 0.0   & 25.59 & 113.81 & 3.191 & 14.194 & 0.478 & 1.1148 & -0.637 & -0.863 & 1.14  & 0.143 & -0.055 & 1.08  & 0.134 & -0.052 & 0.012 & 0.015 & 0.131 & 12.59 & 1.16  & 0.016 & -0.036 & -0.061 \\
\hline
\end{longtable}%
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58220/keep-first-column-on-every-page-of-long-sideways-table/64886#64886) (corrected link) is related to your problem, or can give you some ideas about alternative layouts.

Comment: Your table is not _long_ that is, it has not got that many _rows_ so `longtable` will do nothing much useful with it. Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93808/column-wise-break-of-extra-wide-tables/93810#93810